# input$x_selected_rows only gives the last selected row - Shiny DT Package

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am using the DT package to develop an app. The idea is to let the user select the rows which he/she wants the data for. The issue is that I only get the last row that the user selected and NOT ALL. Here is the part of the code that I am using-

```
     ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),

  # Application title
  titlePanel("selectable Rows"),


  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("stationID",
                "SIDs",value = ""),
      actionBttn("goButton","Go!",color = "default",style = "fill",size = "lg"),

    actionBttn("selected","GetData!",color = "default",style = "fill",size = "lg"),
    uiOutput("download")

  ),


    mainPanel(
      width=6,
      DT::DTOutput("results")

    )
  )
)

server<-function(input, output, session){
  ts_info<-eventReactive(input$goButton,{
    read.table("waterData.csv",header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ",")

  })



  output$results<-DT::renderDT({
    ts_info()
  })



  selectRow<-reactive({

    ids<-input$results_rows_selected
    x1<-ts_info()[ids,]
    return(x1)
     })


  finalset<-eventReactive(input$selected,{
    PATHS<-paste(selectRow()$ts_path, collapse = ",")
    all_data<-read.table("DataRecord.csv",sep = ",", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    data1<-subset(all_data, ts_path %in% PATHS)
    return(data1)
  })



  output$download <- renderUI({


    downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")

  })
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {

      paste("TSDataDownload",Sys.Date(),".csv",sep = "")


    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(finalset(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )    

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

WaterData.csv looks like-
[image]

DataRecord.csv looks like-
[image]

"PATHS" contains the ts_path from the last row that was selected and hence data1 only contains data pertaining to the last row instead of all selected rows. Could someone please help? I have spent too much time on this without any success. Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to help without a minimal reproducible example. You could append the indices of the selected rows in a reactive value.

Comment: @  Stéphane Laurent - I tried to post a reproducible code. Would this help?

Comment: It's not highly minimal and reproducible... your code depends on a CSV file. That said, how do you select the rows ? One by one ? I think (not sure I correctly remember) you have to press Ctrl to select multiple rows, and you should get all the indices. No ?

Comment: @ Stéphane Laurent - instead of using eventReactive, I used reactive and iterated through each selected row- it works. I can select multiple rows without using ctrl. It was a lot of trial and error and honestly, I don't know why it works but it does and I am not complaining :)